# How do I use the ga() function in Google Analytics when the tag is in Google Tag Manager: Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/):

But in my real code, I've used google tag manager to manage google analytics. So I have just one script in the head of my website which belongs to gtm:

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-P8F58CT');

ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto'); // Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined
```

As you can see, I've added `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto')` right after that google tag manager (the same as the tutorial I've linked in the first line of my question). And I have a `ga('send', 'pageview', newURL);` code which will be executed when the page changes using ajax.

The problem is it throws: (as I've commented in code above)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

How can I fix it? Someone told me no need to add `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto');` at all, and gtm will handle it all. **But** in my tests:

- When I open my website (homepage), and run `ga('send', 'pageview', "/adv");` in the console, nothing changes in google analytics and it still points to the homepage.
- When I open my website (homepage), and run `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto');` and then run `ga('send', 'pageview', "/adv");`, then the google analytics will be changed to the `/adv` (not homepage anymore). So I believe `ga('create', 'UA-124402662-1', 'auto');` is needed. But why it is undefined?

Comment: What triggers the page change?

Comment: You should be doing this via GTM because GTM is handling the GA tracking. Following articles are a good read and will possibly provide you with some ideas as to how to go about it.
Virtual Pageviews in GTM
https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/
GTM History Listener
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-history-listener/

Comment: I second Bronwyn - is there a reason you want to do this via ga() instead of using the GTM setup you already have? Or would doing it via GTM be fine if you had instructions?

Answer (score 1):

use `ga` instead of `GTM-P8F58CT`

```
(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-P8F58CT')
```

if it didn't solve the problem use 
`__gaTracker()`